# Filter Listview Using MVVM in Uwp

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

View

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2">
        <RadioButton Content="Verified" IsChecked="{Binding Path=RadioAChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{StaticResource foretwo}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Not Verified" IsChecked="{Binding Path=RadioBChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{StaticResource foretwo}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BillList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bill_Type}" Style="{StaticResource textblock}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bill_Status}" Style="{StaticResource textblock}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bill_Date}" Style="{StaticResource textblock}"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
 public class BillViewModel : BindableBase
{
   IBillDataServices _service;
    public BillViewModel(IBillDataServices service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _billList = _service.GetAllBill();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BillModel> _billList;

    public  ObservableCollection<BillModel> BillList
    {
        get
        {
            return _billList;
        } 
        set
        {
            _billList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BillList");
        }
    } 

    private bool _radioAChecked;

    public bool RadioAChecked
    {
        get { return _radioAChecked;  }
        set
        {
            if (_radioAChecked == true)
            {

            }
        }
    } 

    private bool _radioBChecked;
    public bool RadioBChecked
    {
        get { return _radioBChecked; }
        set
        {
            _radioBChecked = true;
            if (_radioBChecked == true)
            {


            }
        }
    }
```

I have a collection called _billList in my viewmodel(ViewModel).The collection contains Bill_Type,Bill_Status and Bill_Date. Here I need to do a filter in listview. I have values for Bill_Status like ("Yes" and "No") in the collection. if i checked the first radiobutton then the rows which have the Bill_Status = "Yes" should bind to listview. if checked second radiobutton then Bill_Status = "No" rows should bind to the listview. how to do so in uwp? kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get this done, is just filter your collection with Linq and passing that result to your observable collection.

To get this going you should need to keep hold of the original collection with all values, that you can use to do the Linq filtering.

After the filtering you set the result to the observable collection.

Comment: Yes @Depechie. But after fitering the collection, how to retain the old collection??  also have to bind the filtered collection to listview. But Listview itemssource property have binding of old collection only. so how to change that at runtime to be bind to filtered collection??

Comment: You keep a private variable that is the complete unfiltered collection, first time you add all those items to the observable collection that is data bound to the screen. After that when you need to filter, you clear the observable collection and add those items that are the result of the Linq filter on the private variable ( holding the complete list )

Comment: Okay @Depechie. i have done the task and works well. if you can just edit viewmodel and post the code with your answer.